# How to connect to WSL from expo server on Windows machine

Tags: react-native, android-studio, axios, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Environment

Windows10 home
React Native (on windows machine, not WSL)
Android studio 4.0
Virtul Device info
  Name: Nexus S API 30
  Target: Android 10.0+(Google APIs)
  CPU/ABI x86

in WSL2 port 3000, Rails as API server

### Problem

When I use axios from android studio to Rails server on WSL, timeout error appears and even there is no log of Rails.

```
const { rooms } = await createWrapper().post('/hoge/hage');
```

```
//createWrapper
import Axios from "axios";
import {camelizeKeys} from "humps";

export function createWrapper({
  isMultipart = false,
} = {}): any {
  const config: any = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": isMultipart
        ? "multipart/form-data"
        : "application/json",
      // 'X-CSRF-Token': isCsrf ? getCsrfToken() : "",
    },
    baseURL: "http://10.0.2.2:3000",
    // ↑ ***** IPv4 address of WSL also doesnt work *****
    timeout: 300000,
    withCredentials: true,
  };

  const wrapper: any = Axios.create(config);

  wrapper.interceptors.response.use(
    (response: any): any => {
      return {
        ...response,
        data: camelizeKeys(response.data),
      };
    },
    (error: any): any => {
      if (error.code === "ECONNABORTED") {
        return Promise.reject({
          ...error,
          response: {
            data: {
              error_messages: ["timeout"],//***** RESULT HERE *****
            },
          },
        });
      } else if (!error.response) {
        return Promise.reject({
          ...error,
          response: {
            data: {
              error_messages: ["system error"],
            },
          },
        });
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
  return wrapper;
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken , you should do port forwarding, because your app will be running on emulator (it is not the same as connecting from windows host to wsl), wsl network is only exposed to it’s own windows “host”. Here is the link to do port forwarding - https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22

Comment: I solved, Дякую!!

Comment: Always welcome :) Будь-ласка!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check ip address of WSL

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print $2}'
```

exec Powershell (admin), connectaddr is result of ifconfig.
now port sets 3000

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3000 connectaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx connectport=3000
```

confirm

```
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
```